# Securely enforcing user-input file paths within subdirectories

Tags: c#, file, security, directory

I know the solid security recommendation of avoiding accepting user input that you then use to choose a path to read/write a file. However, assuming you have a base directory you want to keep within (such as the root of an ftp folder), how do you best ensure that a given user input keeps us within that folder?

For instance,

```
Path.Combine(_myRootFolder, _myUserInput)
```

could still take us outside of _myRootFolder. And this could also be dodgy

```
newPath = Path.Combine(_myRootFolder, _myUserInput)
if (newPath.StartsWith(_myRootFolder))
   ...
```

given something like "/back/to/myrootfolder/../../and/out/again" from the user. What are the strategies for this? Am I missing a blindingly obvious .NET method I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within ASP.NET applications you can use `Server.MapPath(filename)` which will throw an exception if the path generated goes outside of your application root.

If all you want is a safe file name and you just want all files in there it becomes simpler;

```
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(
        Server.MapPath(
            Path.Combine(@"c:\example\mydir", filename)));
```

If you're outside of ASP.NET like you indicate then you could use `Path.GetFullPath`.

```
string potentialPath = Path.Combine(@"c:\myroot\", fileName);
if (Path.GetFullPath(potentialPath) != potentialPath)
    // Potential path transversal
```

Or you call Path.GetFullPath and then check the start of it matches the directory you want locked to.

Comment: Yeah, that's the sort of functionality I want... except I'm unfortunately in a Windows Service that is batch uploading a bunch of files from one place to another.

Answer (score 4):

I know, that this thread is quiet old, but to prevent following readers from writing code with potential security errors, I think I should point out, that using `Path.Combine(arg1, arg2)` isn't save when `arg2` is directly based on user input.
When `arg2` is for example "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" the `arg1` parameter will be completely ignored and you grant the users of your API or server application full access to the whole file system.

So please be very careful with using this method!

I came up with this solution that should (afaik) be secure:

```
    public static string SecurePathCombine(params string[] paths)
    {
        string combinedPath = "";

        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            string newPath = Path.Combine(combinedPath, path);

            if (!newPath.StartsWith(combinedPath))
                return null;

            combinedPath = newPath;
        }

        if (Path.GetFullPath(combinedPath) != combinedPath)
            return null;

        return combinedPath;
    }
```

**Edit:** There is a new `Path.Join()` method now. Please use that one instead of the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Path.FullPath will do what you need (I didn't test this though):

```
string newPath = Path.Combine(_myRootFolder, _myUserInput);
string newPath = Path.FullPath(newPath);
if (newPath.StartsWith(_myRootFolder)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your example of an FTP server, you should set the users home-directory, and permissions appropriately, such that they can't navigate out of the folder. Any reason you can't do that?

Answer (score -2):

You can parse input string and cut ../ with regex.

Comment: What I'm hoping to avoid is relying on my own knowledge of path shortcuts though. Is "../" definitely the only way of moving up a path? Can you do URL type tricks of encoding in weird unicode characters for example.... I'd rather do a check after the file path has been fully unescaped, if that's possible?